# failed to get `pallet-node-authorization` as a dependency of package `node-template-runtime v4.0.0-dev

Tags: substrate-node-template, polkadot

I am learning "substrate" now and I set dependence according to the tutorial as below:

```
[dependencies]
pallet-node-authorization = { default-features = false, version = "4.0.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
```

Then I run the command "cargo check -p node-template-runtime --release", and got below error:

```
"Caused by:
  failed to load source for dependency `pallet-node-authorization`

Caused by:
  Unable to update https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk.git?branch=polkadot-v1.0.0

Caused by:
  failed to find branch `polkadot-v1.0.0`

Caused by:
  cannot locate remote-tracking branch 'origin/polkadot-v1.0.0'; class=Reference (4); code=NotFound (-3)"
```

so what is the matter?

Comment: I have the same problem as you, how did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

```
Caused by:
  failed to find branch `polkadot-v1.0.0`
```

Please use `branch = "release-polkadot-v1.0.0"` instead. Make sure to check the new naming rules once you switch to the monorepo.

Comment: thank you, but it still failed after use `branch = "release-polkadot-v1.0.0"`;
error: failed to get `pallet-node-authorization` as a dependency of package `node-template-runtime v4.0.0-dev (/home/sw/substrate-node-template/runtime)`

Caused by:
  failed to load source for dependency `pallet-node-authorization`

Caused by:
  Unable to update https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk.git?branch=release-polkadot-v1.0.0

Caused by:
  failed to clone into: /home/sw/.cargo/git/db/polkadot-sdk-cff69157b985ed76

Caused by:
  SSL error: syscall failure: ; class=Os (2)

Comment: Just check your network or maybe use a VPN if you are in China :)

Comment: yes, I use a vpn; it can't be done by vpn?

Answer (score 0):

instead of git = "https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk.git"
use git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git"

They put the wrong url in the tutorial

Comment: this is work 4 me^ big thanks